# Get value of the last record in a record set when using MySql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When selecting an displaying data using PHP and MySql, how can I get value of the last row in a record set? Is there a built in function in MySql or Php to do this?

For Eg (using PDO):

```
select id from table limit 5;

Output:
1
2
3
4
5 -> How can I get this value to pass to a function, all things being the same

 while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
   echo $row['id'];

}
 // The value of id of the last row i.e 5 needs to go into a function
       functionName(id value of last row goes here)
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by _last row_? The last row depends on the filter and the sorting. If you just want the last row, why not just select the last row (with MySQL)? Also, do you know about `LAST_INSERT_ID()`?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is prone to error under particular circumstances.

Comment: @Strawberry correct, there is no guarantee on the order of the returned records when you don't specify an `ORDER`. The records will be returned as they appear on disk, if you do some DELETEs then some INSERTs the order will get mixed up.

Comment: All things being the same as in my question, how can I get the value `5` so I can pass it to a function.

Comment: I don't understand the requirement :s , like this ? 
$last_id = 0
while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
   echo $row['id'];
   $last_id = $row['id'];
}
 functionName($last_id)

Answer (score 2):

```
   $last_id = 0
    while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
       echo $row['id'];
       $last_id = $row['id'];
    }
     functionName($last_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's `end($array)` to get the last item in the array

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. However, in the question above, which would be the array? Is it $row?

Answer (score 0):

Try `MAX()`

`SELECT max(id) FROM table`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
select id from table ORDER BY id DESC limit 5;
```

This way you will get last 5 records.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that good in PHP but, still...

I think `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST)` best suits your requirement.

Example:

```
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT firstnme, lastname FROM employee");
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST);
print "Name: <p>{$row[0] $row[1]}</p>";
```

**Refer to**:
*[Fetching rows from result sets in PHP (PDO)](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CF0QFjAI&url=http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.php.doc/doc/t0023163.htm&ei=cglEUuKtLI2yrgeY0IDIBg&usg=AFQjCNHH5PTym5SYYnp2GWo3F3D27J2TNQ&sig2=eekoWINW9NEDAKLtPDDsRQ&bvm=bv.53217764,d.bmk&cad=rja)*

Answer (score 0):

you can order your select descending and limit 1

select id 
from table 
order by id DESC
limit 1

if you want all rows, and just get the last in php, then as @Shamil said, end() works well